# How to ungroup objects to its parent in Unity using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop, puzzle

When i drag the "block1" group I dragged it as a whole. But I what I want to do is when I dropped into the "slot" it I want to ungroup it and get all the "child(cube)" and re-parent it to the "slot". each cube to each slot. How do I do that? Setting transform.parent = null just removing the "block1" from blocks panel.

[image]

Here's the script:

```html
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragHandler : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler{

 public static GameObject piece;
 Vector3 startPosition;
 Transform startParent;
 public static GameObject cube;


 #region IBeginDragHandler implementation

 public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
 {
  
  piece = gameObject;
  startPosition = transform.position;
  startParent = transform.parent;
  GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;


 }

 #endregion

 #region IDragHandler implementation

 public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
 {
  transform.position = eventData.position;

 }

 #endregion

 #region IEndDragHandler implementation

 public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
 {

  piece = null;
 
  GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
  if(transform.parent == startParent){
   transform.position = startPosition;
   GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;
  }
 }

 #endregion



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are asking here but to set an objects parents there are a few ways

```
public class ParentExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject Child;   
    GameObject ObjectToBeParent;

    void Start()
    {
        //This sets the parent without the worldPos "staying"
        Child.transform.SetParent(ObjectToBeParent.transform, false);
        //This sets the parent
        Child.transform.parent = ObjectToBeParent.transform;
    }
}
```